# Question about strange behaviour of a function

Tags: functions

How is it possible that $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x-2}$ has an asymptote at x=2 whereas $g(x)=\frac{\ln 0.5x}{x-2}$ has no asymptote at x=2? Computing a value for those to functions at this point should result in an asymptote at this point but why on the graph drawn by my computer there is no asymptote on the graph of g(x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln x\ne 0$ when $x=2$, whereas $\ln \frac12x=0$ when $x=2$. This makes quite a difference.

Because $\ln \frac12x$ is *small* when $x$ is near $2$ it can make up for the fact that $\frac{1}{x-2}$ is *big* in that vicinity, and possibly give a product that is neither small nor big.

But $\ln x$ is not particularly small when $x\approx 2$, so it gets overwhelmed by the bigness of $\frac{1}{x-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

At x=2, both the numerator and denominator become 0, so you have an "indeterminant form". To evaluate the limit of this function at x=2, try using L'hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} \frac{\ln \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) }{x - 2} = \lim_{x \to 2^{+}}\frac{\ln x - \ln 2}{x - 2} = \lim_{x \to 2^{+}}\overbrace{\frac{\frac1x}{1}}^{L'Hopital} = \frac12$$

While

$$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} \frac{\ln x }{x - 2} = +\infty$$

Comment: The first two equals signs in this answer are both wrong. Hmm.. the third and fourth are also wrong.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't see it, could you point out the errors?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) }{x - 2}$ is not the same as $\frac{\ln x - \ln 2}{x - 2}$. The first one is $2$, the second is something that depends on $x$.

Comment: $\frac{\ln x - \ln 2}{x - 2}$ is not the same as $\frac{\frac1x}{1}$. Just plug in some values for $x$ and see that they differ.

Comment: $\frac{\frac1x}{1}$ is not the same as $\frac12$, even if we set $x=2$. It becomes $2$ instead.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, okay, I see where you're getting at here. :(

Comment: Finally, $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\ln x }{x - 2}$ is not $ +\infty$, because the value of $\frac{\ln x }{x - 2}$ for an $x$ just slightly _below_ $2$ is a large _negative_ number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're enjoying this aren't you